# JS while loop not reading condition after &&

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon,
I'm trying to create two random numbers with the following condition: They are both between 10 and 99 and the second number is smaller than the first.
I've written the following code:

```
window.onload= function() {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            while (x < 10) {
                 x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
            }
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            while ((y < 10) && (y<x)) {
                 y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
            };
            document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = x;
            document.getElementById("var2").innerHTML = y;
            var z = parseInt( x) - parseInt(y);
            document.getElementById("var3").innerHTML= z;

        };
```

The problem is that whilst both numbers are greater than 10 and smaller than 100, the second number (var y) is not always smaller than the first (var x).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That second while loop isn't executed if y > 10 to begin with.

Comment: This is a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using your browser's script debugger you can set a breakpoint in your code to pause runtime execution and step through the execution line by line, observing the values of your variables and the result of each line of code.  When you do this, what values of `x` and `y` do not satisfy the condition in your second `while` loop and why do you expect them to?

Answer (score 2):

You should not loop but instead just generally do:

```
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + 10
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - 10)) + 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce an offset for your numbers - for the first number, so it begins from 10; for the second number, so it begins from the first number.

```
let min = 10,
    first = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - min)) + min,
    second = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - first)) + first;
```

Actually this allows the two numbers to be equal. Otherwise, if the first number was 100, the second number couldn't be anything.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem:

```js
window.onload= function() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    while (x < 10) {
         x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    }
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    while (y < 10 || y>x) {
         y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    };
    document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("var2").innerHTML = y;
    var z = parseInt( x) - parseInt(y);
    document.getElementById("var3").innerHTML= z
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will answer your question

```
function randomNumbers() {
    var temp_list;
    temp_list = [
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    ];
    temp_list.sort();

    var x = temp_list[1];
    var y = temp_list[0];

    document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("var2").innerHTML = y;
    var z = parseInt(x) - parseInt(y);
    document.getElementById("var3").innerHTML= z;

}
```

If you don't want the same value in x and y:

```
function randomNumbers() {
    var temp_list;
    do {
        temp_list = [
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
        ];
    } while (temp_list[0] == temp_list[1])
    temp_list.sort();

    var x = temp_list[1];
    var y = temp_list[0];

    document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("var2").innerHTML = y;
    var z = parseInt(x) - parseInt(y);
    document.getElementById("var3").innerHTML = z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the cases here

First you are setting x to any value between 0 and 100, then, if that value happens to be less than ten, you continually set it again to another random number which could be in between 0 and 100, until it's greater than 10

First of all, it's possible that it will loop forever if the outcome is less than 10 every time (infinity unlikely, but in the realm of possibility), if you want to get a random number between 10-100 just add ten and take away 10 in the multiplication, like

`Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-10)) + 10`

And you don't need a while loop anyway

Anyways, once x is set to a value between 10 and 100, let's see what else you are doing, let's assume x came out as 90

You are then setting y to a random value anywhere between 0 and 100 (at first), let's say it came out as 3

Then you check first off it it's less than 10, and then keep adding. Again, first off you can use the same equation from above to get a value between 10-100, but anyways,  let's assume y came out at 95

The problem is, the while loop that keeps it under 10 is put together with the condition of being less than x, so that means if it is greater than 10 in the first place, the second condition of the while loop, keeping it less than x, will never be executed, so if y starts as 39 or anything between 11 and 38 , then nothing will happen in the while loop, because the condition of being less than 10 was never fulfilled

So if you want to keep the while loop situation, you can nest two while loops on each other, first keeping it below x, then on the inner one, keep it also above 10

But you don't have to use while loops for this.

First just set the value of x to

`var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-10)) + 10`

Then after, you just keep y in the range of 10 to x, so use the same formula with those start and end values

`var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - 10)) + 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let r = 0; r < 100; r ++) {
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      while (x < 10) {
           x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      }
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      while ((y < 10) || (y > x)) {
           y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      }
 }
```

This code is perfect. The mistake in your code was that you have used and operator in the while loop instead of for loop.